# ngModel.setViewValue not updating the html control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've written a  custom directive to update html controls depending on a condition.

Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/agvTz/212/

The custom directive requires ngModelController, $setViewValue has updated the model value but the html control still shows no value or bunch of spaces in case of textarea. I'd imagine this has nothing to do with the digest cycle since the scope value is updated. Any and all kinda help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont know how to go about it but `$render` should fix your issue.

Comment: @CodeHater: Thank You. That fixes the issue but still doesn't explain what's causing it or what is an elegant way to solve this issue.

Comment: There is no harm in using `$render`. Infact its always suggested to use $render whenever ngModel is updated. Can I have a look at your updated fiddle? You might want to take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393427/angularjs-directives-best-practices-when-using-ngmodel-with-jquery-widget

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController), `$setViewValue`

> does not trigger a $digest.

Therefore, you need to trigger the update via `$render()` method.